# How to make a chest open with redstone or command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-commands

I have Minecraft 1.8.1 in creative mode and I would like to make a chest open visually, using redstone or commands, without touching it.

[image: Close vs open chest.]

Comment: You might be able to do this by editing the tile entity data (which is NBT data).

Comment: @MBraedley Chest's animation is not stored in NBT, it's like the direction an enchantment table's book is facing.

Comment: Switch to survival/adventure mod, stand inside of nether portal block and try to open chest. It will close if you open your inventory or other containers. Also it will not keep opened when world is reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that right now. You could try a different method